# Is this sentence grammatically correct? "te deseo todo la suerte en el mundo"

Tags: verbos, pronombres, españa

I haven't been learning Spanish long so forgive me if this is the most simplest question ever.

I'm wanting to wish my friend from Madrid well with for an exam they have.

So  I'm wanting to know if this sentence "te deseo todo la suerte en el mundo" is grammatically correct, ie is it the correct use of the pronoun and verb etc?

Or would the sentence be "Deseo tú todo la suerte en el mundo"

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [Spanish.SE]! Please note that questions of the ["are there any mistakes in this text?"](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) kind are offtopic and can be deleted. But as this is your first question and you are just starting to learn Spanish, I have posted an answer. Next time try to ask specific questions, like "why is it 'la suerte del mundo' and not 'en el mundo'?". But don't worry, the more Spanish you'll learn, the better your questions will be. Meanwhile, come in and have fun!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first option is almost the right one. Just two notes:

- "Todo" must agree in gender with "[suerte](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YeOou1l)", which is feminine. So it is "toda la suerte".
- In Spanish we say "del mundo", as if the luck were something the world posseses (instead of being something the world contains).

So the final sentence is:

> ¡Te deseo toda la suerte del mundo!

Toda la suerte del mundo para ti también con tus estudios de español. :)